# WordPress Uploading Thumbnail for Custom Post Meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set up a custom post meta field for Thumbnail on each of my posts. This function is being called correctly, and everything works up until the very last line of `update_post_meta`

What's interesting is that I can echo out `$imageURL` and get the correct address, and the file uploads fine. I can even `update_post_meta` with any other value whether it be a string, or another variable within the function but as soon as I try to use `$imageURL` or `$uploaded_file['url']` it just sets the post meta to a blank string.

I've used this snippet on projects that were developed with WordPress earlier than 3.1, but this one is 3.1. Could that have something to do with it? I kind of doubt it, since this seems to be one of those super weird bugs.

```
function tcr_save_thumbnail($post_id, $post) {
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post->ID;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    if(!empty($_FILES['tcr_thumbnail_meta']['name'])) { //New upload
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        $override['action'] = 'editpost';
        $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['tcr_thumbnail_meta'], $override);

        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $attachment = array(
            'post_title' => $_FILES['tcr_thumbnail_meta']['name'],
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_mime_type' => $_FILES['tcr_thumbnail_meta']['type'],
            'guid' => $uploaded_file['url']
        );
        // Save the data
        $id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment,$_FILES['tcr_thumbnail_meta'][ 'file' ], $post_id );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $_FILES['tcr_thumbnail_meta']['file'] ) );
        $imageURL = $uploaded_file['url'];
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tcr_thumbnail_meta", $imageURL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a functionality that has already been implemented in a plugin. try it http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/ It is so complete!